# ADB not working anymore

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb

`$ adb kill-server` 
`$ adb start-server`

None of the above commands give any response the command gets stucked and give no response. It used to work before but dont know why it stopped working.
Android studio also gives a popup saying error initializing adb.

`$ adb devices
List of devices attached`
It gets stuck here

Please Help 
My os Ubuntu 16.4.

Comment: Try doing only $ adb kill-server 5 to 10 times and then run the app in android studio don't do $ adb start-server. This works for me try it and let me know

Comment: `$ adb kill-server` stucks it dont give any response. when i hit enter the command dont run successfully.

Comment: What I do is I do only $ adb kill-server in the Terminal 5 to 10 times and then I go back to android studio and run the application again then it displays the devices to debug the app